# Excel VBA - add column to right and fill with text

Tags: excel, tablecolumn, vba

I want to edit my existing code (below), which copies and pastes tables between 2 workbooks, to do the following:

1. Add new column to the right of "vDB" (at the end) which is a copy of a table from wbTarget
2. Populate the entire column with the text "TOTAL"
3. then paste it to another workbook called "sht1"

   ```
   Dim vDB As Variant
   Dim sht1 As Worksheet
   Dim wbTarget As Workbook 

   'if sheet name is "TOTAL" then...
   If "TOTAL" = Sheet.Name Then

       'copy a given range from the target workbook
       vDB = wbTarget.Sheets(Sheet.Name).Range("b3:i102")

       'paste that range under existing data in the master workbook
       sht1.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB

   End If
   ```

My failed attempt:

```
    Dim vDB As Variant
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim wbTarget As Workbook 

    If "TOTAL" = Sheet.Name Then

        vDB = wbTarget.Sheets(Sheet.Name).Range("b3:i102")

        With vDB
        .ListColumns.Add
        x = .ListColumns.Count
        .Range(2, x) = "Total"
        End With

        sht1.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB

    End If
```

I get a "Object required" error. Any suggestions? I'm fairly new to vba...

Comment: what exactly is `vDb` ? is it a `Worksheet` ? `Range` ? not so clear.

Comment: Its a range (wbTarget.Sheets(Sheet.Name).Range("b3:i102"))

Comment: Are you copying and pasting betwen 2 workbooks ? or only `wbTarget` ?

Comment: I'm copying and pasting between 2 workbooks.

Comment: and you want to add a column in `wbTarget` or in the pastes sheet `sht1` ?

Comment: i want to paste the new column in sht1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the code line below at the end of your current code:

```
' adding "TOTAL" to last column on the right
sht1.Range("A1").Offset(, UBound(vDB, 2)).Resize(UBound(vDB, 1) + 1, 1).Value2 = "TOTAL"
```

Comment: This works but its not dynamic. Is there a way to assign "Total" to each table which is copied? because this code will be put in a loop on many files. Upvote for the effort though!